# Convert JavaScript object keys to an array of keyed objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How can I convert the following JavaScript structure:

```
{
   "product_1": {
        "description": "Paper Towel",
        "type": "homecare",
        "override": true
    },
    "product_2": {
        "label": "Santa Claus statue",
        "type": "seasonal",
        "override": false
    },
    "product_3": {
        "label": "G.I. Joe action figure",
        "type": "toy",
        "override": true
    }
}
```

To:

```
[
    {
        "product_1": {
            "description": "Paper Towel",
            "type": "homecare",
            "override": true
        }
    },
    {
        "product_2": {
            "label": "Santa Claus statue",
            "type": "seasonal",
            "override": false
        }
    },
    {
        "product_3": {
            "label": "G.I. Joe action figure",
            "type": "toy",
            "override": true
        }
    }
]
```

I have **underscore.js** available if that can help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "gimme teh codes" question.

Comment: Why would you want to convert it to a structure where you get a bunch of objects that have a single key whose name you do not know? I see no benefit in the conversion. At least the original gives you a simple means of enumeration.

Comment: @cookiemonster—good point, and the sequence of objects in the array is not necessarily consistent as it will be controlled by some version of *for..in*, so *product_1* may not necessarily be before *product_2*, though with an array at least some kind of sort is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use `_.map()` to iterate over the object, collecting each sub-object into an array.

```
var array = _.map(obj, function (value, key) {
    var new_obj = {};
    new_obj[key] = value;
    return new_obj;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/x2kg3sh3/2/)

Comment: The same thing can be done using `Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){...})`, but I guess the OP likes `_.js`. ;-)

Comment: Underscore.js is probably more portable than that.

Comment: Polyfills for [*keys*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill) and [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) are probably more portable than underscore.js. ;-)

Comment: But if he's already using underscore.js, why should he use a polyfill?

Comment: He shouldn't, I was just suggesting an alternative for others who might come looking.